# NancyFX Asp.Net hosted not called in debugger

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, nancy

(Solved: in two days I can mark my own answer...)

NancyFX hosted with Asp.Net (from template)

I changed the name of my vs project files (manually editing them) and when I run an ASP.Net hosted service I get no indication that the app is running, it does not stop on the root rout nor on the single view and rout that I set up besides the root, and I get a "forbidden" on the root directory (of course, nothing is being called by the IIS) and Not Found for the view (called: dashboard).

At some stage earlier it was working...

When debugging I get a yellow remark on the breakpoint circle and it says: The breakpoint will not currently be hit, no symbols have been loaded.

This happens both in the Bootstrap class and in the modules.

The assembly-name and namespace in the project properties are both Abc.Xyz.Web 
where Abc stands for the company initials and Xyz stands for the project initials.

My web.config has these:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="webPages:Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>

<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />

    <!-- nancy request handler -->
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" type="Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHttpRequestHandler" path="*"/>
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <!-- nancy setup -->
  <!-- see Hosting Nancy with ASP.Net in IIS https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-Nancy-with-asp.net --> 
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <!-- because its a REST site and we will have PUT (and DELETE)  -->
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>  
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <handlers>
      <add name="Nancy" verb="*" type="Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHttpRequestHandler" path="*"/>
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>

<!-- razor -->
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: In the debug properties I have the two DEFINES and in the advanced I have the Debug set for ALL. I emptied the obj and bin folders manually and saved the web.config. All to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I should have shown my packages file, that would have told what the problem was. Somehow in the Nuget, when I installed the Microsoft OWIN hosting package (for security middleware with IdentityServer3) I replaced or removed the Nancy.Asp.Net.Hosting package.

In two days I can mark this as the answer.

Comment: I'm not deleting this, because I'm sure similar things can happen to other programmers. So here's the full checklist: 

Nuget packages as above, web config as per the last edit, build settings as listed above.